# jQuery click to add class, click elsewhere to remove

Tags: jquery, click, addclass

Couldn't find an answer to this anywhere, but essentially I am wanting to add an 'active' link to the anchor when clicked, then remove it when another anchor is clicked. These anchors are hashed hrefs, not real links, as they are acting as a filter.

Here's what I have so far:

```
$('.section-filters a').click(function () {
        $(this).addClass('active');
        var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        $container.isotope({
            filter: selector
        });
        return false;
});
```

Any help?

Thanks,
R

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `removeClass` method.

```
$('.section-filters a').click(function (event) {
    $('a.active').removeClass('active');
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.addClass('active');
    var selector = $this.attr('data-filter');

    $container.isotope({
         filter: selector
    });
    return false; // event.preventDefault()
});
```

Comment: This makes sense; wasn't sure if this would work but I guess the hierarchy helps. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

remember the last active in a variable and do it this way for example:

```
$( '.section-filters' ).each( function() {
    var $active = $();

    $( 'a', $( this ) ).on( 'click', function() {
        $active.toggleClass( 'active' );

        $active = $( this );

        $active.toggleClass( 'active' );

        $container.isotope( {
            filter: $active.attr( 'data-filter' )
        } );
        return false;
    } );

} );
```